# ZF2 - Cookie exception header when posting to remote url

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, zend-framework2

I am trying to post a form via cURL from inside a zend framework 2 console route.

I am doing something like

```
php public/index.php myroute
```

To call the route from terminal. Inside that route is the following:

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request;
$request->setMethod('POST'); 
$request->setUri('http://somesite.com');
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
         'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
]);

/* set post fields */

$aData = array('hello' => 'world');

$request->setContent($request->getPost()->toString());

/* just to look at request string in console */

echo $request->toString()."\n";

/* post the data */

$client = new \Zend\Http\Client;
$client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
```

Problem is that this throws a cookie exception when ran from console:

```
POST http://somesite.com HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

hello=world
======================================================================
   The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
 Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
 Cookie name cannot contain these characters: =,; \t\r\n\013\014 (WEBUK=)
```

If anyone can point out how to get around this I would be very grateful.

The code works in a normal route OKAY...it only complains about the cookie issue when I run it from console.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue for now. I have decided to give up on using zf2 methods for this and instead just use Guzzle.

```
$aData = array('hello' => 'world'); 
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp();         
$r = $httpClient->post('http://somesite.com', [
          'body' => $aData
]);
$response = $httpClient->send($r);
```